# Crossroadsjs routing: how to use it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ember.js, crossroadsjs

I am facing the same problem as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211079/client-side-routing-how-does-it-work) as I am trying to figure out how to use crossroads for a few hours now and nothing seems to work. its webiste is just another poor documented site... I think I am probably daft! I wonder if anyone has made it?

html head,

```
<title>Crossroads</title>
  <script src="js/libs/signals.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/crossroads.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
```

app.js, just as simple as this,

```
crossroads.addRoute('/news/{id}', function(id){  
  alert(id);  
});
```

so I try it out on my localhost browser,

```
http://localhost/crossroadjs/#/news/123
```

nothing happens. I thought it would be `123`??

Comment: If you've checked examples for reference? https://github.com/millermedeiros/crossroads.js/wiki/Examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crossroads doesn't handle history/state change events from the browser.  From [their site](http://millermedeiros.github.io/crossroads.js/):

> **A routes system shouldn't do anything else besides routing.**

Instead, the site recommends [Hasher](https://github.com/millermedeiros/hasher/) for this purpose and gives a rather complete looking example:

```
//setup crossroads
crossroads.addRoute('foo');
crossroads.addRoute('lorem/ipsum');
crossroads.routed.add(console.log, console); //log all routes

//setup hasher
function parseHash(newHash, oldHash){
  crossroads.parse(newHash);
}
hasher.initialized.add(parseHash); //parse initial hash
hasher.changed.add(parseHash); //parse hash changes
hasher.init(); //start listening for history change

//update URL fragment generating new history record
hasher.setHash('lorem/ipsum');
```

Alternatively you could use a different history plugin, or write something yourself.  But crossroads leaves that part up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Crossroads.js gives `crossroads.addRoute(pattern, [handler], [priority]);` API to add route patterns. However, when the first time you load the page Crossroads does not automatically initiate the parser to check against the url of the page. You need to add `crossroads.parse(document.location.pathname);` on you document load to trigger the route. Check out [Crossroads.js Tutorial](http://www.moreonfew.com/crossroadsjs-tutorial-with-examples/).